# Material UI Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Right now, implementation of a Material UI date picker gives the following error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I think that it is calling in a different version of React from the one I'm using? Is anyone facing a similar issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be an issue on the MUI GitHub.

Comment: Add your code snippet and which version you are using for better clearity

Comment: Had to switch to an older version to fix.